# Is there a use case for storing large jars (1-5M) in zookeeper?

Tags: java, osgi, apache-zookeeper

Our team works with a well known OSGI based COTS product that runs as standalone service (it does not interact with multiple instances of itself).   The product contains an API which allows developers to build additional functionality into the project.     This product stores what can be large sized jars (1-5M) in zookeeper along with other configuration data.   The COTS product also includes much opensource (tomcat, zookeeper, many other apache products, etc.).  Thanks to the product being written in java, I have a good understanding of the design and source code.

Our instance of the product has been having issues starting up correctly at times and the issue according to the vendor is that the product is either failing to correctly write or read to zookeeper either when the product is stopping or started (Vendor does not yet know for sure).  This problem only started to appear as we started to add these large jars to the products ./deploy folder.

I do not believe that the node or path cache use cases apply to this product https://github.com/Netflix/curator/wiki/Recipes

Full disclosure:  I currently only have a shallow understanding of zookeeper and have been trying without success to find a recipe/use case where one would use zookeeper to store large binary jars.   I also recognize that I may be asking the wrong question to this audience.

Is the above scenario a common use case for zookeeper?

Comment: It's certainly not a use case zookeeper was designed for, but that's not exactly the question you're asking. And insofar as it's contrary to documented best practices, I certainly wouldn't call it "common" either.

Comment: BTW, storing paths strikes me as **exactly** the right way to do this. Look at [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix/), a language for assembling software build and deployment where your build products are hash-addressed (with a hash of the source code, build process, dependencies, etc) and given a read-only immutable store location. Putting a pointer into that immutable, shared store into zookeeper makes far more sense than trying to put jars there.

Comment: Hi,  Actually your comment is exactly what I and my more knowledgeable co-worker have been thinking as well.  But since my knowledge is shallow, I was looking for thoughts from a larger audience.

Answer (score 0):

ZooKeeper is a consensus store that allows multiple processes to share a common view of a shared resource, it is not a blob store, and should not be used as one.

Firstly, ZooKeeper is a poor choice for storing data in a standalone instance. If you have no need for distributed consensus between multiple readers/writers then ZooKeeper is complete overkill.

Secondly, ZooKeeper nodes are designed to hold *small* data which changes frequently, potentially with many readers watching for changes - the JAR files that you are adding seem not to fit this pattern in that there aren't many readers (the product is a standalone instance) and the JAR files are large.

The default ZooKeeper configuration puts a hard limit of 1MB storage per ZNode, and ideally you store a lot less than that. This can be increased, but it is not advised that you do so. I would strongly recommend that you look into using a proper file store (or even just the file system as your node is standalone) to store these JAR files.